# why file upload gives error cannot read nativeElement of undefined?

Tags: angular

I have the following in my angular 8 app for single file upload

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label>Default file upload</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" class="form-control-sm form-control-sm"  formControlName="importFile" id="importFile" (change)="onFileChange($event.target.files)"  >
    <span id='val' #labelImport></span>
 </div>
```

TS file

```
  @ViewChild('labelImport',{static:true})
    labelImport: ElementRef;
  onFileChange(files: File) {
      // this.labelImport.nativeElement.innerText = Array.from(files)
      //   .map(f => f.name)
      //   .join(', ');

      this.fileToUpload = files;
    this.employeeMaster.image = this.fileToUpload;
    this.labelImport.nativeElement.innerText = files.text();

    //console.log(this.fileToUpload);
    }
```

When i select an image it gives the following error

[image]

[Here the video of the issue](https://youtu.be/gFpvjuLGR_o)

What i want to do is i need to store the selected file in cache each time when user selects a file

But why it gives the error?

Note: If the information provided not adequate enough to give an answer then please ask me for more : )

Comment: did you try with `{static:false}`?

Comment: @Moshezauros it worked further i wanna ask how do i set file to it one run time programatically and set the file name label to it?

Comment: @eutychostfar I think the reason why you couldn't get the files name is due to not addressing it as array in `event.target.files` as this `files` is of type array. If you only want to have one file uploaded, you can straight define `event.target.files[0]` or you might want to loop through it and get the index with `event.target.files[i]`

Answer (score 0):

you can debug ts code in chrome, by adding debug points ;) https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#loc
as indicated by [belle Zaid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9508627/belle-zaid) files is of type `array` so you have to do:

HTML: `multiple` files can be uploaded at the same time

```
<input
      #file
      (change)="onFilesAdded($event)"
      accept="image/*,.pdf"
      multiple
      type="file"
/>
```

ts with method name `onFilesAdded` indicating that we may get multiple files

```
  @ViewChild("file") file;

  numberOfFiles: number = 0;

  onFilesAdded(fileInput: ProgressEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void {
    const newFiles: FileList = fileInput.target.files;
    Array.from(newFiles).forEach(newFile => {
      this.numberOfFiles++;
      console.info(this.numberOfFiles);
      console.info(newFile);
    });
  }
```

test it (only nice to know):

```
describe('onFilesAdded should', () => {
    it('get called on change event', () => {
      inputEl = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input[type=file]');
      spyOn(component, 'onFilesAdded').and.callThrough();

      inputEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));

      expect(component.onFilesAdded).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

here the [stackblitz link for angular file upload](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload-ypzxbp)
btw. you can use a simple service with getters and setters up to an NGRX store to store the uploaded files